# Excel time division

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I am trying to get excel to divide a duration of EG 18:14:24 into 10.
This works out to be around 1 hour and 49 min and change - 1:49:00 ish
I can work it out by hand and have looked for it, but not found an answer.
If i try to divide 18:14:24 by 10 it shows 13:49:26 for some reason.
I have also tried to use % of day and no luck.
The formatting is hh:mm:ss in the cell. Basically i am subtracting 24% of a day and dividing by 10, independent of date.

Comment: Hi @Drew Price,,, check my post I'm sure this is what you were looking for,, in case of any issue,, reply through comments,, better share some sample data with us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**:Caveat:**

Since OP has not shared any sample data, therefore I've assumed some.

*I would like to suggest two different methods:*

[image]

- Enter time 18:14:24 in cell I18.
- Formula in cell J18: `=I18/10`
- Formula in cell J19: `=TIME(18,14,24)/10`

*Cell J18 & J19 has format HH:MM:SS.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Drew Price ,, keep asking.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know the second method, and the first one was not working. I got it working by accident i think, by changing the formatting back and forward a few times in the precedent cells and it changed the behaviour.

Comment: @DrewPrice,, apply cell format `HH:MM:SS" as I've mentioned in last row of my post, it will work. Second one is using TIME function with fixed value like 18 is Hour, 14 is Minute and 24 is second. Method 1 handle any TIME value as one I've entered in cell I18.